# Count the retweets using SQL statement only

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I've tweets in a set of JSON files and I need to count the retweets for each user.
I know that there is an attribute called "retweet_count" but its removed form the files for educational purposes:). So, I can use only SQL statement.

First, Its requested to register a table from all JSON files "tweets_sample" as below:

```
tweets_sample = sqlContext.read.json("/tweets28a_samples")
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(tweets_sample,"tweets_sample")
```

then create a table for only 4 columns as follow:

```
users_agg = sqlContext.sql("SELECT user.screen_name, MAX(user.friends_count) AS friends_count, count(_id) AS tweets, MAX(user.followers_count) AS followers_count FROM tweets_sample WHERE user.lang='en' GROUP BY user.screen_name ORDER BY tweets DESC")
Result:
---------------+-------------+------+---------------+
|    screen_name|friends_count|tweets|followers_count|
+---------------+-------------+------+---------------+
|       anaoromi|         6258|    16|           6774|
|    RosaMar6254|         6208|    14|           6245|
```

then created another table which will be the INNER JOIN for both two tables as follow:

```
retweeted = sqlContext.sql("SELECT user.screen_name, tweets, friends_count, followers_count, count(retweeted_status) AS retweeted FROM tweets_sample AS A INNER JOIN user_agg AS B ON A.user.screen_name = B.screen_name AND A.user.friends_count = B.friends_count and A.user.followers_count = B.followers_count WHERE user.screen_name='PSOE' GROUP BY user.screen_name, tweets, friends_count, followers_count ")
```

but here the retweet comes with null value.
I tried many ideas and SQL statements but with no luck.
So, any one can help me with that?

Below the schema structure:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created_at: long (nullable = true)
 |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |-- place: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bounding_box: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- country_code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- place_type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweeted_status: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- followers_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- friends_count: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id_str: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- lang: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- screen_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- statuses_count: long (nullable = true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace >> ON A.user.screen_name to ON A.retweeted_status.user.screen_name